# Use toSentenceCase on function parameter Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

In a Codecademy assignment, I would like to add a case to the parameter of my function, so whenever a person searches on the name `"JoNes"`, the parameter gets "translated" to `"Jones"`. (this is just to play with Javascript, not mandatory)

According to [this](http://www.javawithus.com/programs/converting-string-to-different-cases-upper-lower-toggle-camel-sentence-case) website, there is a case called `Sentence Case` (he also calls it Title Case), however, whenever I use `.toSentenceCase`, it returns a syntax error on Codecademy. I would like to know if the following code would normally work and that it's Codecademy that doesn't support it in this assignment (in other words: it doesn't expect it, so anything different than the expected is wrong) OR if it's not possible to add a case to the parameter of a function like this.

Bonus: If it's the latter, how would you fix the input coming in through `search();`, so it always corresponds to the demand of the first letter being upper-case, while the rest is lower case?

The function:

```
var search = function(lastName.toSentenceCase) {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        if (lastName === contacts[i].lastName) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        }
    }
}

search("JoNes");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
String.prototype.toSentenceCase= function() {
return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1).toLowerCase()
```

}

Then:

```
"JoNes".toSentenceCase();
```

becomes: `Jones`

Comment: Beautiful solution, thanks! I guess by the fact that we have to create our own `toSentenceCase` that it's not an officially supported "case".  Would, purely out of interest, toUpperCase work on a parameter, or should it be applied on the search-string?

Comment: Adding methods to prototypes of Built in objects are not exactly a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
String.prototype.toSentenceCase = function () {

    var stringArray = this.split(" ");

    for (var index = 0; index < stringArray.length; index++) {

        stringArray[index] = stringArray[index].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArray[index].substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return stringArray.join(" ");
}

//test:
var testString = new String("JoNe Is A NaMe");
console.log(testString.toSentenceCase());
```